# Copy spreadsheet on trigger - onOpen

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create such process: You open a spreadsheet and on trigger onOpen i want to copy that spreadsheet to users drive. I do not know why code below is not doing that, i tried version with

```
  spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
```

but is was not also not working

```
function onOpen(e){
 var spread = e.source
 var dest = DriveApp.getRootFolder();  
 var name = "NEW NEW spreadsheet test"
 var newfile = DriveApp.getFileById(spread.getId()).makeCopy(name,dest);
 Browser.msgBox('File will appear on your Drive in a moment');
 SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(newfile)
}
```

Please i am looking to suggestions what i am missing or misinterpreting.
Thank You!

Comment: `onOpen(e)` has limited auth-mode. Not sure you can access drive and create a spreadsheet with this authorisation.

Comment: Code does not execute for viewers -only editors. Consider using a webapp to allow sign in and copy of the document.

Comment: Or you can simply share the link with `/copy` at the end rather than `/edit`. This way, You don't need full drive permission of every user and you respect their right to "refuse" to make a copy.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
function onOpenTrigger(){
 var spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var dest = DriveApp.getRootFolder();  
 var name = "NEW_NEW_spreadsheet_test"
 var newfile = DriveApp.getFileById(spread.getId()).makeCopy(name,dest);
 var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(newfile);
 Browser.msgBox('File will appear on your Drive in a moment');
 SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(newSpreadsheet)
}
```

I've made it work using this steps:

1. rename onOpen by another name, here onTriggerOpen
2. manually create a trigger that runs on opening of the document
3. first execute the function from the google App IDE to allow actions for user

`onOpen` is set to a `LIMITED` authorisation so not sure if it will work for other users that haven't executed `onOpenTrigger`from the IDE.

Also you are passing a `File` object instead of a `spreadsheet` object inside `setActiveSpreadsheet(spreadsheet)` so one solution is to use `SpreadsheetApp.open(file)` first

**REFERENCES**

[Open()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#open(File))

[setActiveSpreadsheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#setActiveSpreadsheet(Spreadsheet))

[Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)